# Documenting an anonymous function in JSdoc

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I'm trying to get JSDoc to work like so:

```
export const beginRefreshGames = () => {
  /**
   * @param {Snowflake} snowflake
   * @param {function} dispatch
   * @param {function} getState
   */
  return async (dispatch, getState, snowflake) => {
    const games = await snowflake.games.getGames()
    dispatch(refreshGames(games))
  }
}
```

I want to return the async function without binding it to a variable. If I assign it directly then the JSDoc works fine, but I'm hoping it's possible without,